# How to access pybind11 array_t<> data pointer in debugger

Tags: c++, pybind11

I would like to access the data pointer for a `pybind11::array_t<T>` typed NumPy array wrapper, while stepping in a debugger. As below, the debugger does not know the type of `array_t<T>`, so the `data(...)`/`mutable_data(...)` accessors are not available.

```
(lldb) p o
(pybind11::array_t<unsigned long long, 16>) $24 = {
  pybind11::array = {
    pybind11::buffer = {
      pybind11::object = {
        pybind11::handle = (m_ptr = '0x10872fe40')
      }
    }
  }
}
(lldb) p o.data()
error: no member named 'data' in 'pybind11::array_t<unsigned long long, 16>'
(lldb) p o.data(0)
error: no member named 'data' in 'pybind11::array_t<unsigned long long, 16>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the implementation of `array_t::data` in pybind11's `numpy.h`, a solution is to use the `pybind11::detail::array_proxy` to access the data pointer:

```
(lldb) p ((uint64_t*)pybind11::detail::array_proxy(o.m_ptr)->data)[652]
(uint64_t) $26 = 87112
```